# Binding textblock text to property on load

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to display the number of records retrieved by the query after the window loads. Here's what I have in my XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="numRecordsAnalyzed_TAtab" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,4" Grid.RowSpan="2"> 
                        <Run Text="Records Found: " Foreground="{StaticResource Foreground}" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Numrecords}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="12"/>
    </TextBlock>
```

Here's my c#:

```
private int numOfrecords = 0;
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Numrecords
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(numOfrecords); }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("NumOfrecords");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Then I add this to get the number of records and when I debug I see that the variable holds the number and everything but nothing is displayed in the window when the window launches:

```
numOfrecords = OpenTradesQuery.Count();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **need to raise `PropertyChanged` event to notify GUI to update**.

Declare property of type `int`, WPF will automaically call `ToString()` on your property, you need not to worry about that.

```
public int Numrecords
{
    get { return numOfrecords; }
    set
    {
        if(numOfrecords != value)
        { 
           numOfrecords = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Numrecords");
        }
    }
}
```

Set the property:

```
Numrecords = penTradesQuery.Count();
```

---

You can set `DataContext` in code behind after `InitializeComponent()` in constructor of Window/UserControl:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Also, you can set it in XAML at root level like this:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: it's not working still, I'm looking online people use datacontext somewhere do I need to add that? this is code behind how would I add this datacontext @Rohit Vats

Comment: I was hoping that you already have `DataContext` set. I have updated the answer to include that as well.

Comment: Ok so now I got some writing however the number didn't update it was 0 @Rohit Vats

Comment: PropertyName is `Numrecords` but you are passing incorrect property name in `OnPropertyChanged` method. It should be `Numrecords` and not `NumOfrecords`. I have updated in an answer as well.

Comment: Thanks! it was that and I put the datacontext after numofrecords was updated and it worked putting it under initialization wouldn't work but anyways works now thanks @Rohit Vats